# Trying to implement BRISQUE with OpenCV in Python, but the module is not found

Tags: python, opencv

I’m trying to implement image quality assessment into my project using OpenCV and would like to use BRISQUE to generate a quality score.  This is in Python with Anaconda3.

From the documentation, the Python code should be:

```
cv.quality.QualityBRISQUE.compute( img )
```

but ‘quality’ after cv is not being recognized.

I’ve installed opencv-contrib-python to gain access to the extra modules that should include ‘quality’. Also, I have implemented these lines

```
import cv2 as cv
img = cv.imread(path)
grey = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurScore = cv.Laplacian(grey, cv.CV_64F).var()
```

so I am getting some functionality out of OpenCV.

Is there something I am missing in my attempt to implement BRISQUE image quality assessment?

Comment: you will need an opencv package that has the contrib modules included.

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/trying-to-use-brisque-but-quality-module-is-not-recognized/9438

Answer (score 1):

I have tested it, and it works well. I think you have to set the path to the "brisque_models" as explained in the next link: https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/quality

Find below the code and results in my IDE also with Anaconda:

```
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread("IMG_0813.JPG")
grey = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurScore = cv.Laplacian(grey, cv.CV_64F).var()
score = cv.quality.QualityBRISQUE_compute(img, "brisque_model_live.yml", "brisque_range_live.yml")

print(f' >> Blur Score: {blurScore}')
print(f' >> BRISQUE Score: {score}')

cv.namedWindow("Output", cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv.imshow("Output", img)
k = cv.waitKey(0)
```

Output of the above code:

```
 >> Blur Score: 49.96128887699266
 >> BRISQUE Score: (4.900564193725586, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

If you do not set the paths of the models such as `cv.quality.QualityBRISQUE_compute(img)`, the result produce is show below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quick_tests.py", line 7, in <module>
    score = cv.quality.QualityBRISQUE_compute(img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'QualityBRISQUE_compute'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - QualityBRISQUE_compute() missing required argument 'model_file_path' (pos 2)
>  - QualityBRISQUE_compute() missing required argument 'model_file_path' (pos 2)
```

I hope you solve the issue.

Comment: please replace those screenshots by the *text* they contain.

Comment: You should provide the text version of the printout if you want others to help you out. Screenshots make it harder for others to help